# Glide- Pause image loading onscroll recyclerview

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have a RecyclerView that loads images from the server.
When I scroll the scrolling is quite jerky.
I am using glide to load images
I feel that images are being loaded every time the recycler view is being scrolled.
So could anyone please tell how to stop loading images onscroll...

Thanks..

Answer (score 4):

You're probably doing something odd, like resizing the view, when the image load completes. Make sure you're not triggering layout calls or doing other expensive things when images are loaded. It's almost always possible to get relatively smooth scrolling while still loading images with Glide.

That said, you can use [`pauseRequests()`](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/360/com/bumptech/glide/RequestManager.html#pauseRequests()) and [`resumeRequests()`](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/360/com/bumptech/glide/RequestManager.html#resumeRequests()) to stop/start image loading when the user starts/stops scrolling:

```
// Scrolling starts.
Glide.with(fragment).pauseRequests();
...
// Scrolling stops.
Glide.with(fragment).resumeRequests();
```

Comment: I  tested my app in Android 4.4 and 5. In 5.0 there was jerk in scrolling but in 4.4 it was smooth. So is this the version problem or what?

Comment: Is the device different on 5.0? Usually L+ is smoother because it uses ART, which handles garbage collection much more efficiently than dalvik.

Comment: I cannot understand what you are asking?(Is the device different on 5.0)

Comment: @user2969165 He meant for example: if the 4.4 device was a Galaxy S4 and the 5.0 was a Nexus 6; or both 4.4 and 5.0 was running on two physically different Galaxy S4s?

Comment: once Glide.with(fragment).pauseRequests(), you should also align with Glide.with(fragment).load(file).into(imageView) or it will pause nothing

Answer (score 1):

```java
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Recyclerview.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).resumeRequests();
                }
                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).pauseRequests();
                }
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            }
        });
    }
});
t.start();
```